# Cannot connect to vtiger database

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, vtiger

I am trying to implement vtiger's API to connect my android application to it's server. I have added the API to the libs folder and then compile the .jar file. I then use the documentation to connect to the server in java.

boolean result = true;

```
WSClient client = new WSClient("http://en.vtiger.com/wip");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);



    result = client.doLogin("username", "Accesskey");

    if(!result)
    {
        System.out.println("Login failed!");
        System.out.println(client.lastError());

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Login Successful");
    } 
 }
```

However, I always get the Login failed and no error present. The problem is that when I open the WSClient.java class from inside the .jar, the program states that no sources can be found. I have downloaded these files from http://forge.vtiger.com/frs/?group_id=181&release_id=573 and do not know what to attach as a source. Maybe this is why I cannot connect to the server since I am using the right username and access key supplied by vtiger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Its an example based on https://demo.vtiger.com/ for login

public class Login extends Activity {

```
  //URL to get JSON Array
  private static String url = "https://demo.vtiger.com/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=admin";

  //JSON Node Names
  private static final String TAG_RESULT = "result";
  private static final String TAG_TOKEN = "token";

  // contacts JSONArray
  JSONArray contacts = null;

  String token = null;
  String sessionId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {
               dialog.setMessage("Loging In... Please wait...");
               dialog.show();
              }
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
            JSONObject result;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                // Creating new JSON Parser
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    result = json.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULT);
                      JSONObject json_result = json.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULT);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    token = json_result.getString(TAG_TOKEN);

                    //Importing TextView

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String username="admin";
                String accesskeyvalue = "w9OweWKUS4a5sSL";
                String accessKey=md5(token + accesskeyvalue);

                //For debugging purpose only
                //System.out.println(accesskeyvalue);
                //System.out.println(token);
                //System.out.println(accessKey);

        String data = null;

            try {
                data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                        + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("accessKey", "UTF-8") + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(accessKey, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        //System.out.println(data);

        // Send data
        try
        {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("https://demo.vtiger.com/webservice.php?operation=login");

         // Send POST data request
          URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
          wr.write( data );
          wr.flush();    

        // Get the server response    
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                   // Append server response in string
                   sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response
        System.out.println(text);
        sessionId = text.substring(41, 62);
        //System.out.println("doInBackground()"+sessionId);



    return null;    
    }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);    
                dialog.dismiss();
               }

         }.execute();

    } 

    public String md5(String s) 
    {
    MessageDigest digest;
        try 
            {
                digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                digest.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length());
                String hash = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
                return hash;
            } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return "";
    }
```

*Change the variables as per your need*

you don't need to use any additional jar files.